# ACF - Can't get custom post type by taxonomy

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy, advanced-custom-fields

Although I've read many other answers with the same question on StackOverflow none of them where able to fix the issue I have.

I'm using ACF and have a custom post type called "services".
The CPT has a custom taxonomy called "category", this returns the TermID of the taxonomy.

This was working before when I used a standard taxonomy, but since i've switched to the ACF taxonomy it has stopped working.

```
//This works fine
$serviceName = $wp_query->query_vars['test'];

//CURRENT The loop issue with ACF which doesnt work
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $serviceName
             )
          )
    );


//OLD The loop when using standard taxonomy that works
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'services',
        'category_name' => $serviceName,
    );


//Display
$service_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

In Functions.php I have created a function which makes the ACF categories filter out the ones I don't want. This is to prevent the user choosing categories which aren't services.

```
function service_categories( $args, $field, $post_id ) {

    $args['orderby'] = 'count';
    $args['order'] = 'DESC';
    $args['include'] = '6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 16';
    return $args;

}
```

This works on the dashboard, however I wonder if this at all may be interfering at all?

Thank you for your time.

EDIT:

Also noticed when you view all the CPT's the category tab is blank, not sure why this is since as far as I'm aware the ACF should overwrite this anyway.

Comment: Why are you using ACF to select Categories on a Custom Post Type? Can't you just use Wordpress' built in taxonomy boxes? Also, if the issue was being able to filter out only Service Categories, couldn't you create a separate taxonomy (ie, service_category)?

Comment: @Samyer I did initially unfortunately their were a few issues with that.1. It showed categories across the entire website rather than just the ones specific to that service. 2. The ability to make the category a requirement (without using a plugin or js). 3. From a UI standpoint, it just didn't look very good, and wasn't entirely obvious a user had to select it.